# Can I store objects in Python class members?

Tags: python, actionscript-3, pygame, instantiation

I'm writing a game in Python with the Pygame2 multimedia library, but I'm more accustomed to developing games with ActionScript 3. In AS3, I don't think it was possible to store an object in a static variable, because static variables were initialized before objects could be instantiated.

However, in Python, I'm not sure if this holds true. Can I store an object instance in a Python class variable? When will it be instantiated? Will one be instantiated per class or per instance?

```
class Test:
    counter = Counter() # A class variable counts its instantiations
    def __init__(self):
        counter.count() # A method that prints the number of instances of Counter

test1 = Test() # Prints 1
test2 = Test() # Prints 1? 2?
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean static? You can set static variables just like any other variable in ActionScript 3.
Or maybe static means something else i Python (as compared to ActionScript 3)?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I was thinking of constants. Either static variables or constants were set at compile time, before any objects could be instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
As with most python try it and see.

It will be instantiated when a Test object is created. ie your assignment to test1
The counter object is created per class

Run the following to see (to access the class variable you need the self

```
class Counter:
  def __init__(self):
    self.c = 0

  def count(self):
    self.c += 1
    print 'in count() value is ' , self.c
    return self.c

class Test:
  counter = Counter() # A class variable counts its instantiations 
  print 'in class Test'
  def __init__(self):
    print 'in Testinit'
    self.counter.count() # A method that prints the number of instances of Counter

test1 = Test() # Prints 1
test2 = Test()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
class Test:
  counter = 0
  def __init__(self):
    Test.counter += 1
    print Test.counter
```

And it works as expected.